# ORA-06575: Package or function is in invalid state

Tags: sql, oracle, function

```
create or replace function checkBLProgression(getpatient_id in number)
  return varchar2
is
  res varchar2;
begin
  res := 'M1 progressed';
  return(res);
end;

select checkBLProgression(102934) from dual;
```

Above is my code which I am trying to run but getting error:

> ORA-06575: Package or function is in invalid state

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You must to declare a length of `res` variable. Use for example `res varchar2( 100 );` and recompile the function again. Else watch for warnings after executins `CREATE FUNCTION ...` command, if you see some warnings, then run `SHOW ERRORS` because it indicates that trere are some errors in your code.

Comment: Thank you Kordirko it solves my problem